# How to reset router's password through FTP

Tags: router, passwords, ftp, reset

I forgot the credentials to log into my WiFi router, so I decided to check for vulnerabilities using a simple framework called RouterSploit to take back control. The framework found the ftp credential of the router which has not been changed (user/user). My question is, how can I use the FTP credential to login to take back control of my router and reset its password in port 80 (192.168.1.1 login screen) ? I'm a complete newbie so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It would be easier to just reset the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most [FTP servers do not allow changing FTP password](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_change_password#ftp) using the FTP protocol itself.

And even if your router does, if the FTP password is separate from the router administrator password, it won't help you much.

You will have to find another way to restore your router. FTP protocol is not the right way.